# List Activities in a Package

Tags: android, list, android-activity, package

I am starting to write an Android application that is going to be a reference utility.

As of the moment I am organizing the activities into packages so I would like to write a class that will list the activities in the package to the view to establish the hierarchy.

I do not know know how to ask a package for that information.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this? Tips for a better application design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward if you look at the [PackageManager Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Here are the rough steps:

Use `Context.getPackageManager()` to get an instance of `PackageManager`.

Then call `PackageManager.getPackageInfo()` on the desire package. That will return an `ApplicationInfo` object which has a public member `ApplicationInfo.ActivityInfo`.

`ActivityInfo` is an array of all the `<activity>` tags from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

If this isn't clear read the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) docs and then follow the links until you get to [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured there was a reflective(?) class somewhere but I wasn't sure what to look for.

Answer (score -2):

Another way is to create an XML file with your metadata.  I hope it's helpful because you can access easily.

```
<packages>
 <package>
  <activities>
   <activity>
   </activity>
  </activities>
 </package>
</packages>
```

Comment: Yes, or a database but I want to eliminate redundancy wherever possible.